# OpenCV won't play video in Colab notebook. cv.VideoCapture object not returning shape

Tags: python, opencv, video, attributeerror

*I'm trying to follow along a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ig2ibBkc7Q) on OpenCV, in which the person in the video uses a Jupyter notebook to run the code but when I tried to run it Jupyter didn't recognize cv2, even after attempting to pip install opencv-python and opencv-contrib-python. I tried to import cv2 in PyCharm but apparently openCV doesn't work on python 3.10.5 and I'm not willing to downgrade.*

*So I decided to run the code in a Colab Notebook instead, which is the following:*

```
import cv2 as cv
from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
```

*And of course here is the second block:*

```
#Read the image
img = cv.imread("/content/opencvimages/catimages/cat.jpg")
cv2_imshow(img)

#This image displays properly when the block is ran.
```

*This particular block is the one giving me issues:*

```
capture = cv.VideoCapture("/content/opencvimages/dogvideo/Puppy4740.mp4")

while True:
  isTrue, frame = capture.read()

  if not isTrue: 
    break

  cv2_imshow(capture) #<-------------- The problem seems to be this method.

  if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==ord('d'):
    break

capture.release()
```

*So when I try to run the code: it returns an AttributeError:*

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-28-845b4263fabf> in <module>()
      7     break
      8 
----> 9   cv2_imshow(capture)
     10 
     11   if cv.waitKey(20) & 0xFF==ord('d'):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/colab/patches/__init__.py in cv2_imshow(a)
     20       image.
     21   """
---> 22   a = a.clip(0, 255).astype('uint8')
     23   # cv2 stores colors as BGR; convert to RGB
     24   if a.ndim == 3:

AttributeError: 'cv2.VideoCapture' object has no attribute 'clip'
```

*I thought that was a little sus so I ran a separate block of code placed before the previous one:*

```
capture = cv.VideoCapture("/content/opencvimages/dogvideo/Puppy4740.mp4")
print(capture.shape)
```

*Which returned this error:*

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-c75dc112b69d> in <module>()
      1 capture = cv.VideoCapture("/content/opencvimages/dogvideo/Puppy4740.mp4")
----> 2 print(capture.shape)

AttributeError: 'cv2.VideoCapture' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

*So for some reason, cv2.VideoCapture is not doing its job when it comes to the video. I checked, double-checked, and even triple-checked to make sure the right file and path was placed on the method but it is not processing the video correctly and so I can't move forward with the tutorial. Also, as you can see the object itself is not returning a shape. Not sure what the issue is here.*

Answer (score 2):

you seem to confuse the VideoCapture object (think: a VR) with an image read from it ...

you want to show the **image retrieved from the capture**, not the capture instance itself, so:

```
cv2_imshow(frame)
```

Comment: Ok that seems to have solved part of my problem. In the tutorial the image displayed is shown in the form of a video but in my notebook when I applied that code it is simply printing one image after another and not deleting the previous one. Also, it is taking a long time to generate them.

Comment: you need to pay attention to detail. `cv2_imshow` is a shim by google colab because the code runs on google servers, which can't open their own GUI on your local computer. the dude in the tutorial runs jupyter, on his own computer, so he can use `cv2.imshow`, which is the function from OpenCV. -- in general, ask the people whose tutorials you are following. they are the teachers, it's their responsibility to answer the questions they caused.